# I want 2 widgets side-by-side to fill 100% of div

Tags: wordpress, html, widget

In wordpress, I have 2 widgets of different widths which I want to sit side-by-side and fill the entire width of my main content divider (these are not sidebar widgets).  I've already got the widgets made and they basically look correct, but I have trouble getting them to fill exactly 100% of the divider.  To play with the widget size, I'm adjusting the following code in style.css:

DIVIDER 
 .col-940 {width: 100%;}

WIDE WIDGET 
 .col-540 {width: 57.446808510638%;}

NARROW WIDGET 
 .col-340 {width: 36.63%;}

PROBLEM #1:
When I tweak the widths they end up either not filling the space completely, or overfilling it and bumping the 2nd widget down to the next row.

PROBLEM #2:
When viewing the site on a mobile device, the widgets naturally stack up and cannot sit side-by-side (no problem here, this is desired).  However, the widths of each widget are supposed to stretch to 100% of the available space, right?  Instead they appear to vary in width 10-20%.

`

|-------------------------------------| |----------------------|

|-------------------------------------| |----------------------|

|-------------------------------------| |----------------------|

|-------------------------------------| |----------------------|

|-------------------------------------| |----------------------|

`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own problem.  In style.css I adjusted the column widths until everything fell into place it now it displays correctly.

Here are the two things I tweaked in Style.css

.col-340 {width: 36.9%;}

.col-540 {width: 57.446808510638%;}

These two total "94.3468" percent of the width.  So the secret/solution is that you need to leave almost exactly 7.5% for the margins or padding.  If the two columns you use total greater than 94.3468, everything gets bumped down and messy.